# How get pressed keys in mousePressEvent method with Qt?

Tags: python, qt, key, mouseevent

I'm trying to get which keys are pressed in the `mousePressEvent` method of a window. 
I know how get some key with the `keyboardModifiers` method of `QApplication` but it only works for few keys.
A piece of code to start with:

```
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
import sys



class SurfViewer(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(SurfViewer, self).__init__()
        self.parent = parent
        self.setFixedWidth(300)
        self.setFixedHeight(100)
        self.globallayout = QVBoxLayout()
        l_a = QLabel('A')
        self.globallayout.addWidget(l_a)
        self.setLayout(self.globallayout)

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        if event.buttons()== Qt.RightButton :
            print('Right click')
            #Call a function which return pressed keys (whatever the key)
        if event.buttons()== Qt.LeftButton :
            print('Left click')
            if QApplication.keyboardModifiers() == Qt.ControlModifier:
                print('Ctrl')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = SurfViewer(app)
    ex.setWindowTitle('window')
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_( ))
```

So what I miss is a method to ask for which keys are pressed, not only keys availlable with `keyboardModifiers`. I looked at the `QKeyEvent Class` but I don't know how to force its call from the `mousePressEvent`

### update

I tried the answer of @Changlong :

```
Changlongfrom PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
import sys



class SurfViewer(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(SurfViewer, self).__init__()
        self.parent = parent
        self.setFixedWidth(300)
        self.setFixedHeight(100)
        self.globallayout = QVBoxLayout()
        l_a = QLabel('A')
        self.globallayout.addWidget(l_a)
        self.setLayout(self.globallayout)

        self.keys=[]

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        if event.buttons()== Qt.RightButton :
            print('Right click')
            self.keyPressEvent()
        if event.buttons()== Qt.LeftButton :
            print('Left click')
            if QApplication.keyboardModifiers() == Qt.ControlModifier:
                print('Ctrl')

    def keyPressEvent(self, event):
        if event.key()== Qt.Key_A :
            print('A pressed')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = SurfViewer(app)
    ex.setWindowTitle('window')
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_( ))
```

but if I maintain the A key pressed, the `keyPressEvent` is continuously called. So I get :

```
A pressed
....
A pressed
A pressed
Right click
A pressed
....
A pressed
A pressed
```

Comment: You should listen to the `QKeyEvent` events and keep track of which keys are down.

Answer (score 2):

For your reference:

```
def keyPressEvent(self, event):
    if event.key()== Qt.Key_A :
        print('A pressed')
```

Hope to be helpful.

result:

```
$ python3 pyqtqkeyevent.py 
QWidget::setLayout: Attempting to set QLayout "" on SurfViewer "", which already has a layout
Right click
Left click
A pressed
```

Your code is fine when mouse right/left buttons pressed.

## Update：

```
def mousePressEvent(self, event):
    modifierPressed = QApplication.keyboardModifiers()
    modifierName = ''
    if (modifierPressed & Qt.AltModifier) == Qt.AltModifier:
        modifierName += 'Alt '

    if (modifierPressed & Qt.ControlModifier) == Qt.ControlModifier:
        modifierName += 'Ctrl '

    if (modifierPressed & Qt.ShiftModifier) == Qt.ShiftModifier:
        modifierName += 'Shift '

    if (modifierPressed & Qt.MetaModifier) == Qt.MetaModifier:
        modifierName += 'Meta '

    if (modifierPressed & Qt.KeypadModifier) == Qt.KeypadModifier:
        modifierName += 'Keypad '

    if (modifierPressed & Qt.GroupSwitchModifier) == Qt.GroupSwitchModifier:
        modifierName += 'GroupSwitch '

    if event.buttons() == Qt.RightButton:
        print('Right Click: ',modifierName)
        #self.keyPressEvent()
    if event.buttons() == Qt.LeftButton:
        print('Left Click: ',modifierName)


def keyPressEvent(self, event):
    if event.key() == Qt.Key_A:
        print('A pressed')

def keyReleaseEvent(self, event):
    if event.key() == Qt.Key_A:
        print('A Release')
```

Result:

```
$ python3 pyqtkeymouseevent.py 
QWidget::setLayout: Attempting to set QLayout "" on SurfViewer "", which already has a layout
Left Click:  Ctrl 
Left Click:  Shift 
Left Click:  Meta 
Left Click:  
Left Click:  
Left Click:  Ctrl Shift 
Left Click:  Alt Ctrl Shift Meta 
Left Click:  Alt Meta 
Left Click:  Ctrl Meta 
Left Click:  Alt Ctrl 
Left Click:  Alt Shift 
Right Click:  
Right Click:  Alt Ctrl Shift Meta 
Right Click:  Ctrl 
Right Click:  Shift 
Right Click:  Meta 
A pressed
A Release
```

Is this what you want?

Single press Alt and mouse button click, do not work in my Desktop(Ubuntu Xfce), because window manager eat it as "drag window operation".

Comment: If I do that, the keyPressEvent is call continuously ( the time the key is pressed) What I would like to do is just ask once when I click right on the mouse.

Comment: run your code, it works fine: $ python3 pyqtqkeyevent.py 
QWidget::setLayout: Attempting to set QLayout "" on SurfViewer "", which already has a layout
Right click
Left click
A pressed

Comment: I edit my post. I think I misunderstand something from your answer.

Comment: Update, please check.

Comment: I think I have an issue with `keyPressEvent`. when I keep the A key pressed for a while, the console print: A pressed 
A Release
A pressed
A Release
A pressed
A Release
A pressed...for ever. however I shouldn't go in the `keyReleaseEvent` because I don't release A key.

Comment: I tried this with PySide2. Alt and Shift modifiers won't work with PySide2. Any idea why and how to fix it?